Solution to exercise 1.1.12 of Terence Tao's Random Matrix Theory notes
Tao's notes: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/matrix-book.pdf
I understood Example 1.1.3. by explicitly writing down every element in hyperplane V.
However, in Exercise 1.1.12 below, there seems to be no such primitive solution.

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a finite field, and let $V$ be a subspace of
$\mathbb{F}^n$ for some finite n. Let $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ be drawn
uniformly at random from $V$. Suppose that $V$ is not contained in any
coordinate hyperplane in $\mathbb{F}^n$.

Show that each $X=i$ is uniformly distributed in $\mathbb{F}^n$.
Show that for any $k \ge 2$, $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ is $k$-wise independent iff $V$ is not contained in any hyperplane which is definable using at most $k$ of the coordinate variables.
Show that $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ is jointly independent iff $V = \mathbb{F}^n$.


Intuitively, I know the first statement holds because the assumption on V guarantees that $X_i$ is not a constant and there is no special value in $\mathbb{F}$.
Could someone help me? Thanks.
